# How to choose an alternative transistor

Tags: transistors

I'm trying to assemble a guitar effects pedal and can't find the right transistor for the project.

The question is whether it is possible to replace transistors Q7 Q9 and Q10 ([*2SC945*](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/5971/NEC/2SC945.html)) with [*KTC945*](https://alltransistors.com/adv/pdfdatasheet_kec/ktc945.pdf) according to the scheme. These transistors are very similar except for the collector current.

[Link to the circuit](http://toshi.life.coocan.jp/review/images/analogchorus/ce3_mod_schematic.pdf)

Comment: General purpose transistors, most anything will do. 2N3904, BC550, etc.

Comment: Mouser and Digikey still sell these:  https://www.onsemi.com/download/data-sheet/pdf/ksc945-d.pdf

Comment: @Ste Kulov
Hi Ste. Does this transistor suits my needs? According to the datasheet, it has a different beta value. Will it lead to some change in the circuit?

Comment: In the 2SC945 data sheet, there's a small chart titled "Classification of \$h_{FE2}\$" with letters assigned to each section.  There is no such thing as a 2SC945, but there is a 2SC945Q and a 2SC945P.  According to the chart the 2SC945Q has an \$h_{FE2}\$ between 135-270, and the 2SC945P has an \$h_{FE2}\$ between 200-400.  Your schematic doesn't show a letter at the end of 2SC945, so it likely doesn't matter which gain range you use (i.e. inconsequential to the circuit design).  Onsemi only makes the KSC945Y, which is 120-240.  That's a typical value for a BJT so I think it will work fine.

Comment: @Ste Kulov thank you for the exhaustive answer